# How to use travis-ci to build modern c++ using modern cmake?

Tags: c++11, gcc, cmake, travis-ci

Is it possible to use travis-ci to build a c++ application/project that uses cmake, gcc-6 and g++-6?

Comment: I have clang-3.9 and g++-6 https://github.com/gelldur/EventBus

Comment: Fyi. https://blog.lukaspradel.com/continuous-integration-for-cmake-projects-using-travis-ci/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Configuring travis to use the right compiler is a bit tricky.
This is how it can be done:

First of all you need to set the distribution to trusty (the newest version of ubuntu that's supported by travis-ci) and require sudo.

```
dist: trusty
sudo: require
```

Next up we set the language and the compiler:

```
language: cpp
compiler: gcc
```

So far so good. Now we can go about setting up the apt install configuration:

```
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    packages:
      - gcc-6
      - g++-6
      - cmake
```

This adds the ppa for the newer version of our build tools and installs them. The next step is setting up links to the new gcc and g++. `/usr/local/bin` is being searched before `/usr/bin`, so that our newly installed version 6 compilers are going to be accessible with just `gcc` and `g++`. The beginning of your `script:` should look like this:

```
script:
    - sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-6 /usr/local/bin/gcc
    - sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-6 /usr/local/bin/g++
```

Add the next line as well, if you want to verify the versions of those tools:

```
    - gcc -v && g++ -v && cmake --version
```

The versions that come back from these commands are as follows:

```
gcc: 6.2.0
g++: 6.2.0
cmake: 3.2.2
```

That's basically it. The complete .travis.yml looks like this:

```
dist: trusty
sudo: required
language:
  - cpp
compiler:
  - gcc
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    packages:
      - gcc-6
      - g++-6
      - cmake
script:
  # Link gcc-6 and g++-6 to their standard commands
  - ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-6 /usr/local/bin/gcc
  - ln -s /usr/bin/g++-6 /usr/local/bin/g++
  # Export CC and CXX to tell cmake which compiler to use
  - export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-6
  - export CXX=/usr/bin/g++-6
  # Check versions of gcc, g++ and cmake
  - gcc -v && g++ -v && cmake --version
  # Run your build commands next
```

Comment: The `unlink` but there is i) a more Debian/Ubuntu way via `update-alternatives` and/or ii) you can just set `CXX`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This was the first stable thing I was able to come up with. I'll edit the unlink part and use CC and CXX instead.

Comment: Also, you do not need `sudo` -- you are root in that script. Lastly, another trick is to link to a new `/usr/local/bin/g++` (Debian will not fill `/usr/local/` it is guaranteed empty) as that will be search before `/usr/bin`.  Just in case the build scripts to not respect `CC`, `CXX`, ...

Comment: Awesome that's exactly the kind of inside I was missing. :D

Comment: I think the answer should be updated to include "modern cmake" as well. What version are you getting from the trusty repo?

Comment: The CMake version I'm getting is 3.2.2, which is a quite recent one.

Comment: @henne90gen I just noticed that I force `g++-4.9` over the default `g++-4.8` in one of my `.travis.yml` and then run this command: `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.9 50`. I think that is *exactly* what you were after (module picking `g++-6`, of course) and better than either config var or soft link in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Update: When I use this, I get CMake3.9.2, so that's a plus!

Comment: Fyi. https://blog.lukaspradel.com/continuous-integration-for-cmake-projects-using-travis-ci/

Answer (score 8):

I found some errors in @henne90gen's answer (or maybe they've just changed). Specifically:

- You don't need `sudo`.
- You don't need to install CMake from apt. This will install an ancient CMake 2.8 from Trusty. Fortunately the build image already comes with CMake 3.9.2 (as of now).
- `gcc-7` doesn't get installed to `/usr/local/bin` and it is already in the `PATH`.

This should work:

```
dist: trusty
language: cpp
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    packages:
      - gcc-7
      - g++-7
script:
  - export CC=gcc-7
  - export CXX=g++-7
  - ...
```

Here's a longer example that includes a modern version of Qt (with QtSVG which I'm using), and works on OSX and Linux.

```
os:
  - linux
  - osx

language: cpp

dist: trusty

addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
      - sourceline: "ppa:beineri/opt-qt-5.10.1-trusty"
    packages:
      - gcc-7
      - g++-7
      - qt510-meta-minimal
      - qt510svg
      - qt510imageformats
      - qt510tools

before_install:
  - if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "osx" ]]; then
      brew update ;
      brew install qt5 cmake ;
      brew link --force qt ;
    fi

script:
  - if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" ]]; then
      export CC=gcc-7 ;
      export CXX=g++-7 ;
      source /opt/qt510/bin/qt510-env.sh ;
    fi
  - cmake --version
  - qmake --version
  - ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `dist: bionic`. This should meet most of the cases.

Comment: Why do you prefer bionic over xenial or trusty? Just curious. Trusty seems EOL now so bionic and xenial seem preferable over trusty but why bionic instead of xenial? Bionic seems newer than xenial so that's another reason for me. Are there others? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Adding a semi-related solution after struggling with this for way too long. Hopefully, it helps someone else avoid spending the amount of time I did going through the cycle of updating travis.yml, committing, waiting for Travis...repeat til it works.

I had a C extension in a Python project that started producing failing tests in Travis, yet passed locally. Eventually, I tracked it down to the old version of `gcc` on the xenial environment. Here's the Travis YAML file that finally solved the issue for me:

```
dist: xenial
language: python
before_install:
  - sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test -y
  - sudo apt-get update -q
  - sudo apt-get install -y gcc-7
  - export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-7
python:
  - "3.6"
  - "3.7"
install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - python setup.py build_ext --inplace
script:
  - python run_tests.py
```

As an aside, anyone else find they want to trigger a Travis build on a specific commit to find out exactly where a problem started?

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for this answer! I tried it out and it installs g++7.5.0. However I'm still getting some errors with `variant`s being undefined. Do you know how to have cmake or make use -std=c++17?